# AS3 Using a building outline as a preloader

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I was wondering how to go about doing a preloader that slowly reveal a building outline line by line.

Could anyone point me in the right direction or tutorial? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have two solutions:

### Flash

In Flash your draw your outline and separate every line to put it in a MovieClip. Then you have to put each clip on a different layer (Ctrl+A, right click->distribute to layers) and order them.

In your code you have to hide every line.

```
for (var iClip:int = 0; iClip < _house.numChildren; iClip++)
{
    _house.getChildAt(iClip).visible = false;
}
```

Then in your code you will have a function listening to `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS`, let's call it `onProgress`

```
private function onProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var totalClips:uint = _house.numChildren;
    var lastClipToShow:uint = Math.ceil(totalClips * event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal);
    for (var iClip:int = 0; iClip < lastClipToShow; iClip++)
    {
        _house.getChildAt(iClip).visible = true;
    }
}
```

On each call of this listener you will show every line from the deepest to a fraction of the total number matching the amount of data loaded.

### Code

The second solution will require you to enter the coordinates of every segment in your outline in an `Array`.

```
private const HOUSEDATA:Array = [   [[0, 0], [10, 15]],
                                    [[25, 354], [32, 341]],
                                    [[321, 54], [78, 1]],
                                    [[534, 5], [23, 5]]
                                    ];
```

Then, again in `onProgress`

```
private function onProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var totalSegments:uint = HOUSEDATA.length;
    var lastSegmentToShow:uint = Math.ceil(totalSegments * event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal);
    graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x0000FF);
    graphics.clear();
    for (var iSegment:int = 0; iSegment < lastSegmentToShow; iSegment++)
    {
        graphics.moveTo(HOUSEDATA[iSegment][0][0], HOUSEDATA[iSegment][0][1]);
        graphics.lineTo(HOUSEDATA[iSegment][1][0], HOUSEDATA[iSegment][1][1]);
    }
}
```

And voilà!